# What is the simplest way to get all sub-folder and files inside a Folder using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have the following code to get the sub-folders and files inside a folder, but this code will not retrieve any sub-folder and files found at deeper level. so can anyone advice how i can get all the files and folders within a folder?

```
Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
FileCollection files = folder.Files;
FolderCollection folders = folder.Folders;
context.Load(files, fs => fs.Include(f => f.ListItemAllFields));
context.Load(folders, fs => fs.Include(f => f.ListItemAllFields));
foreach (File f in files)
    {

    }
foreach (Folder fo in folders)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below logic to get all the files from a folder and it's sub folder, the below caml query has RecursiveAll which brings up all the files from a folder including all it's sub folders. Alter the below `clientContext.Load` with required fileds to be included.

````
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> " +
                "<Query>" +
                "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" />" +
                                "<Value Type=\"Text\">/sites/test/list/folder1</Value>" +
                             "</Eq>" +
                "</Where>" +
                "</Query>" +
                "</View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = DocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
    {
       console.writeline(item["Title"]); 
    }```
````

Comment: this CAML will only return a single item not all the folders and files..

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following code to achieve it.

```
Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
context.Load(folder);
context.ExecuteQuery();

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                         <Query>
                         </Query>
                     </View>";
camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
ListItemCollection listItems = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("library3").GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(listItems);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (ListItem oListItem in listItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", oListItem["FileLeafRef"]);
}
```